# undefined reference to xxxxxxx, linking issue stm32cube

Tags: c, build, compiler-errors, stm32

I am unable to compile my code successfully due to undefined references.

I am using the STM32Cube IDE compiler which is based of atollic true studio.

The undefined references are due to headers not linking.

I have included the headers into my main program and have included them in the include path for the compiler.

```
#include "base64_codec_transport.h"
#include "line_buffer_transport.h"
#include "modem_ussd_transport.h"
#include "thingstream_transport.h"
#include "client_api.h"
#include "client_platform.h"
#include "client_set_callback.h"
#include "custom_modem_transport.h"
#include "debug_printf_core.h"
#include "log_client_transport.h"
#include "log_modem_transport.h"
#include "log_protocol_transport.h"
#include "log_transport.h"
#include "modem2_transport.h"
#include "modem_set_callback.h"
#include "modem_transport.h"
#include "predefined_topics.h"
#include "quectel_modem2_config.h"
#include "ring_buffer_transport.h"
#include "sdk_data.h"
#include "serial_transport.h"
#include "sim7600_modem2_config.h"
#include "transport_api.h"
#include "ublox_modem2_config.h"
```

[image]

The consol errors are below:

[image]

All these functions are defined in their respective headers as follows, to give one example.

```
#define line_buffer_transport_create    Thingstream_createLineBufferTransport
```

which then points to 
`extern ThingstreamTransportResult Thingstream_line_buffer_deliver(ThingstreamTransport *self);`

I have also rebuilt the index multiple times and still no success.

I don't know what else to do to solve this.

Comment: have you actually defined these functions?

Comment: I am trying to import an SDK, I see in the release folder there is  a '.a' file, I have never done this before but I suspect you are going to tell me I need to include it which I have no idea how to, if you could guide me it would be much appreciated.

Comment: .h files are nt libraries.

Comment: You are going to need to add the library to the linker, we need the name of the library, the path and the current settings of the `MCU GCC Linker` and it's subtabs